# PORT registers in PIC18

Tags: pic, proteus

I'm having a problem with PORT registers in PIC18 MCUs. It doesn't matter what value I put on a pin the PORT register never changes it's value. I don't know if it's a programming error or some bug Proteus. I made sure port is digital and not analog. I tested two programs using CCS and C18:

**C18:**

```
// CONFIG1H
#pragma config OSC = XT         // Oscillator Selection bits (XT oscillator)
#pragma config FCMEN = OFF      // Fail-Safe Clock Monitor Enable bit (Fail-Safe Clock Monitor disabled)
#pragma config IESO = OFF       // Internal/External Oscillator Switchover bit (Oscillator Switchover mode disabled)

// CONFIG2L
#pragma config PWRT = OFF       // Power-up Timer Enable bit (PWRT disabled)
#pragma config BOREN = OFF      // Brown-out Reset Enable bits (Brown-out Reset disabled in hardware and software)
#pragma config BORV = 3         // Brown Out Reset Voltage bits (Minimum setting)

// CONFIG2H
#pragma config WDT = OFF        // Watchdog Timer Enable bit (WDT disabled (control is placed on the SWDTEN bit))
#pragma config WDTPS = 32768    // Watchdog Timer Postscale Select bits (1:32768)

// CONFIG3H
#pragma config CCP2MX = PORTC   // CCP2 MUX bit (CCP2 input/output is multiplexed with RC1)
#pragma config PBADEN = OFF     // PORTB A/D Enable bit (PORTB<4:0> pins are configured as digital I/O on Reset)
#pragma config LPT1OSC = OFF    // Low-Power Timer1 Oscillator Enable bit (Timer1 configured for higher power operation)
#pragma config MCLRE = OFF      // MCLR Pin Enable bit (RE3 input pin enabled; MCLR disabled)

// CONFIG4L
#pragma config STVREN = ON      // Stack Full/Underflow Reset Enable bit (Stack full/underflow will cause Reset)
#pragma config LVP = OFF        // Single-Supply ICSP Enable bit (Single-Supply ICSP disabled)
#pragma config XINST = OFF      // Extended Instruction Set Enable bit (Instruction set extension and Indexed Addressing mode disabled (Legacy mode))

// CONFIG5L
#pragma config CP0 = OFF        // Code Protection bit (Block 0 (000800-001FFFh) not code-protected)
#pragma config CP1 = OFF        // Code Protection bit (Block 1 (002000-003FFFh) not code-protected)
#pragma config CP2 = OFF        // Code Protection bit (Block 2 (004000-005FFFh) not code-protected)
#pragma config CP3 = OFF        // Code Protection bit (Block 3 (006000-007FFFh) not code-protected)

// CONFIG5H
#pragma config CPB = OFF        // Boot Block Code Protection bit (Boot block (000000-0007FFh) not code-protected)
#pragma config CPD = OFF        // Data EEPROM Code Protection bit (Data EEPROM not code-protected)

// CONFIG6L
#pragma config WRT0 = OFF       // Write Protection bit (Block 0 (000800-001FFFh) not write-protected)
#pragma config WRT1 = OFF       // Write Protection bit (Block 1 (002000-003FFFh) not write-protected)
#pragma config WRT2 = OFF       // Write Protection bit (Block 2 (004000-005FFFh) not write-protected)
#pragma config WRT3 = OFF       // Write Protection bit (Block 3 (006000-007FFFh) not write-protected)

// CONFIG6H
#pragma config WRTC = OFF       // Configuration Register Write Protection bit (Configuration registers (300000-3000FFh) not write-protected)
#pragma config WRTB = OFF       // Boot Block Write Protection bit (Boot block (000000-0007FFh) not write-protected)
#pragma config WRTD = OFF       // Data EEPROM Write Protection bit (Data EEPROM not write-protected)

// CONFIG7L
#pragma config EBTR0 = OFF      // Table Read Protection bit (Block 0 (000800-001FFFh) not protected from table reads executed in other blocks)
#pragma config EBTR1 = OFF      // Table Read Protection bit (Block 1 (002000-003FFFh) not protected from table reads executed in other blocks)
#pragma config EBTR2 = OFF      // Table Read Protection bit (Block 2 (004000-005FFFh) not protected from table reads executed in other blocks)
#pragma config EBTR3 = OFF      // Table Read Protection bit (Block 3 (006000-007FFFh) not protected from table reads executed in other blocks)

// CONFIG7H
#pragma config EBTRB = OFF      // Boot Block Table Read Protection bit (Boot block (000000-0007FFh) not protected from table reads executed in other blocks)

#include <p18cxxx.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void main(void) {

    ADCON1bits.PCFG = 0b1111;
    TRISBbits.TRISB0 = 1;
    while(1);
}
```

**CCS:**

```
#include  <18F4520.h>             // PIC16F877A
#use      delay(clock=12M)         // Cristal de 4MHz

#fuses HS             //High speed Osc (> 4mhz for PCM/PCH) (>10mhz for PCD)
#fuses NOIESO         //Internal External Switch Over mode disabled
#fuses NOBROWNOUT     //No brownout reset
#fuses NOWDT          //No Watch Dog Timer
#fuses NOMCLR         //Master Clear pin used for I/O
#fuses NOPBADEN       //PORTB pins are configured as digital I/O on RESET

void main (void){

   input(PIN_B0);
   while(1);

}
```

Here are two pictures demonstrating what I mean, as you can see in both pictures the PORT register has the exact same value:

[image]

[image]

This happens on Proteus 7.7 SP2 and Proteus 8.1 SP1.

Comment: This may not be the root cause, but you've selected a crystal in the configuration settings but did not actually put a crystal on the device. Better to use the internal oscillator for this experiment.

Comment: Well it doesn't matter in Proteus. If I select internal oscillator Proteus simulates it in some PIC. If you set external crystal it just uses the frequency you set for the PIC.

Answer (score 1):

PORTB on that particular part has internal pull-ups that can be enabled/disabled with the nRBPU bit in the INTCON2 register. If they are enableb you will always read the same value on that pin so snsure your pull-ups are disabled and try again.

Comment: This is not how it works in real. If this is true, it's a problem of Proteus. In real, pulled up ports can still be tied low by external hardware, what Andres is simulating here.